# How can I implement Camera2 API for external usb camera?

Tags: android-studio, android-usb, usb-camera

I am trying to create an application for tablet which uses external camera. It should capture and re-capture image as well as save image.

I tried implementing third party libraries like [libuvccamera](https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera) but it is not detecting any camera. Which other method/library can I use to implement this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, worked for me https://github.com/jiangdongguo/AndroidUSBCamera. It's based on libuvccamera but much more convenient and requires little to make things work